# How to parse a dictionary and JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, rest, dictionary

I have a weird setup where I am trying to parse a dictionary of an array of dictionaries.

How is this parsed in Swift?

I get the json object as below, but now sure how to proceed.

```
if let earthquake_data = json as? NSDictionary {



}
```

-

```
{
"earthquakes": [
{
"datetime": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
"depth": 24.4,
"lng": 142.369,
"src": "us",
"eqid": "c0001xgp",
"magnitude": 8.8,
"lat": 38.322
},
{
"datetime": "2015-04-25 06:13:40",
"depth": 15,
"lng": 84.6493,
"src": "us",
"eqid": "us20002926",
"magnitude": 7.9,
"lat": 28.1306
},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON array in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840203/parsing-json-array-in-swift)

Comment: Root is dic type, inside it an array with key earthquakes. That array comprises of members which are of dic type themselves. Make a class name EarthQuake with all these attributes and make objects of it using your array members data. What do you think is the problem here?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use this library to parse JSON on Swift: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

***Example:***

```
if let earthquake_data = JSON(json){

   let dateTime = earthquake_data["earthquakes"][0][datetime].stringValue

}
```