# Parse JSON Data Array with Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I am using the following code.  It only works if the JSON data does not start with a '[' character.  It works fine for JSON data starting with a '{' character.  There is a similar question here: [Parsing JSON array in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840203/parsing-json-array-in-swift) but most of the methods are deprecated and I was unable to get the code to work.  Here is the JSON call I am using:

```
guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any]        else {
    print("Error: Could not parse JSON!!!")
    return
}
```

I tried removing all options and using allowFragments and mutableLeaves among others.  From what I understand mutableContainers is a default setting but I have been trying whatever I can.  Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Here is a sample of the JSON data I am working with:

{ "CREATED_BY" = "Domain\USER"; "CREATED_DATE" = "2011-09-30T15:00:13"; STATUS = U; "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" = 039000292; "UPDATED_BY" = "Domain\USER""; "UPDATED_DATE" = "2014-08-02T13:22:01"; }

Comment: You are casting the object to `[String: Any]` which suppose an array.

Comment: Please add a sample `JSON`

Comment: Here is the JSON I am working with:

Comment: that was printed from the the var json so it doesn't have brackets.  I am still trying to iterate through and get specific elements.  Any advice would be great.

Comment: Code in comments is a bad idea. Please delete your comment and post the code as an update to your question, that way it can be formatted decently. As a second piece of advice I would suggest to read up on JSONDecoder and `Decodable` protocol, the much more Swift-y way of doing JSON. It will also allow you to define a general date format which will be applied automatically if appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the [] signifies that the json is an Array of objects, so you need to cast this to an array. You can do this by either casting it to [Any] or by casting it to an array of dictionaries (which is what it really is).

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Any]
    let json2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] 
} catch {
    print("Error: Couldn't parse JSON. \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

So provided the following json to the above block:

```
let jsonString = """
    [{
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Test",
        "team1": "thingy team",
        "team2": "clicky team",
        "category": "4",
        "end_date": "1415217600",
        "cat_name": "new thingy",
        "team1_bets": 1,
        "team2_bets": 1
    }]
"""
```

you would end up with an output of the following:

```
let json = Optional([{
    "cat_name" = "new thingy";
    category = 4;
    "end_date" = 1415217600;
    id = 5;
    name = Test;
    team1 = "thingy team";
    "team1_bets" = 1;
    team2 = "clicky team";
    "team2_bets" = 1;
}])
let json2 = Optional([["team2_bets": 1, "name": Test, "id": 5, "team1_bets": 1, "team2": clicky team, "team1": thingy team, "category": 4, "cat_name": new thingy, "end_date": 1415217600]])
```

The main difference between the two is that the contents of `json` are an array of `Any` objects, which would then need to be cast to whatever data type you're working with.  The `json2` array is an array of dictionaries, which you would then need to cast the `Any` objects but you still have the keys available.

Answer (score 3):

Then it may be an array

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [Any] 
    print(json)
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

> This [ ]     means Array  ---- >      [Any]
>
> while this { } means Dictionary ----->   [String:Any]

Answer (score 0):

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [NSDictionary]; //jsonArray
print(json![0].value(forKey: "name")!); //jsonObject
```

Comment: Please explain how it solves the problem.